# Grails under Eclipse/STS debugging with hot update

Tags: eclipse, debugging, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm attempting to debug a grails application and when I change controller code (method bodies primarily) Eclipse pitches a fit and says it can't perform a hot update giving me the option to terminate/restart etc.

I had this problem a number of years ago with an ant compiled project using the standard javac compiler.  One of my co-workers pointed out there is a "compiler adapter" for using the eclipse JDT compiler adapter.

I'm not sure how to utilize this under grails.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I've always just hit continue and ignored the error. Grails will still do the hot swapping without a problem.

Comment: Seriously consider trying out IntelliJ IDEA, Ultimate Edition.  Grails support is awesome!

Comment: I'm seeing this with STS 2.9.0 (and now 2.9.1) and Grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using STS 2.8.1 and Grails 1.3.7